# Extract List of Object property from object list

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, generic-list

If I have a list of student object

```
var List<Student> = new List<Student>();
```

and this is the Student object data **(ID,Name)**

How can I extract list of Student IDs only using Linq To Entities

Please Advice,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Enumerable.Select`:

```
List<int> studentIDs = students.Select(s => s.ID)
                               .ToList();
```

(although i'm not sure how it is related to linq-to-entities)